# Emotion as dependent variable. Can I refer to emotion as a deep/broad dependent variable?

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, predictor, dependent-variable

I am testing a hypothesis with emotion as my (Y) dependent variable.

I am wondering if you can refer to emotion as a deep/broad dependent variable? Becausse it is may be influece by a broad range of factors.

Definition of broad: "covering a large number and wide scope of subjects"

I wanna say that the variable is being influenced by multiple factors (a broad range of psychosociological factors). Background (my model has a low variance R2 = < 0.20). I want to say that this may be caused because the variable is "broad". Can i use those words or is it to ambiguious.

Comment: Please explain what "deep/broad" is intended to mean.  Could you provide a definition?

Comment: I wanna say that the variable is being influenced by multiple factors (a broad range of psychosociological factors). Background (my model has a low variance R2 = < 0.20). I want to say that this may be caused because the variable is "broad". Can i use those words or is it to ambiguious.

Comment: So far, you haven't provided any basis for characterizing your variable like this.

Comment: i am using the article of ashfoth and humphrey as a basis. Ashforth, B. E., & Humphrey, R. H. (1995). Emotion in the workplace: A reappraisal. . Human relations, 48(2), 97-125.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a bit off topic, but I don't think "emotion" makes any sense as a variable.  How did you operationalize it?

*Particular* emotions - such as anger, love, etc - could be variables.  But "emotion"?  No.

Comment: Thx for your reaction. I have measured emotion with the JAWS Job affective well-being scale. In my analysis i made a distinction between positive emotions (PA = positive affect) and negative emotions (NA = negative affect).

Comment: Then you are mislabeling your variable.  You should call it something like "Job-related Affective Well-being " if you are using the full scale, "negative" and "positive" affect if you are using two scales, or the names of the subscales if you are using all of them. See the [JAWS website](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~pspector/scales/jawsover.html).

Comment: And I don't think "broad" is an accepted description of a variable.

Comment: Thank you!! I have explained those variables in detail as wel. But reffer to them as emotion becaus of language differences. (As you already can tell. English is not my native tongue).